# Check for duplicate element in a list and if it is duplicate insert another element in its place, keeping the list size intact

Tags: java, list, duplicates

I'm trying to generate the 2-letter State Code, I'm storing the countries in a list of strings. Now, the criteria are:-

1. The First letter of the state code must be the first letter of the state. For ex- If the state is **Alabama**, **the first letter must be A.**
2. The second letter of the state code can be any random letter from the word.
3. Now if we give 5 states then it should return 5 unique values.

PS: I'm attaching the code below, here I'm trying to convert the list into a set but the set is removing the duplicates, I want all the distinct values without repetition.

**Input:[Alabama, Alaska, Alain, Bombay, Borland]
Expected Output:[AL, AK, AA, BO, BR]**

```
public class RadnomStateGenerator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
        stateList.add("ALABAMA");
        stateList.add("ALASKA");
        stateList.add("ALAIN");
        stateList.add("BOMBAY");
        stateList.add("BORLAND");
        System.out.println(stateList);
        HashSet<String> hset = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String string:stateList)
        {
            char   fWord  = string.charAt(0);
            int    value  = (int) (Math.random() * string.length() - 1);
            char   sWord  = string.charAt(value);
            String newstr = ((Character.toString(fWord) + Character.toString(sWord)).toUpperCase());
            hset.add(newstr);
        }
        System.out.println(hset);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to loop, checking that the size of the set has grown after the add operation. If it hasn't you need to stay in the loop and generate again, else exit the loop

Comment: @g00se, can you include the code snippet, I already tried that but it's not getting in my head.

Comment: You tried what? Whatever you did try, please post the code

Comment: _The second letter of the state code can be any random letter from the word._ Then how can you expect some predefined values?  for Alabama, Alaska, Alain the answers could be "AA, AL, AN" or "AB, AS, AA", or "AM, AA, AL".  You should also keep track of mapping the abbreviation to the actual state name.

Answer (score 0):

When adding an entry to a set, the method `add` returns `true` only if the set has changed that is the entry has been added.  This can help detect duplicates and therefore attempt to create another code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> stateList = Arrays.asList("ALABAMA", "ALASKA", "ALAIN", "BOMBAY", "BORLAND");
    System.out.println(stateList);

    Set<String> hset = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    
    Random r = new Random();
    
    for (String string : stateList) {
        int len = string.length() - 1;
        String first = string.substring(0, 1);
        while (true) {
            String code = first + string.charAt(1 + r.nextInt(len));
            if (hset.add(code)) { // set changed
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(hset);
}
```

Example:

```
[ALABAMA, ALASKA, ALAIN, BOMBAY, BORLAND]
[AA, AK, AI, BY, BL]
```

or

```
[ALABAMA, ALASKA, ALAIN, BOMBAY, BORLAND]
[AM, AL, AI, BB, BR]
```

It's worth to mention that chances to get `AA` for `ALABAMA` is ~50% because of three `A`'s after the initial one.